# value de una opción seleccionada en un select (select2)

Tags: vue.js, select2, binding

Estoy iniciando con vue Js y estoy intentando pasar como parámetro a una función ajax el valor seleccionado de un select, pero no logro hacerlo, puesto que siempre me toma el valor que por defecto asigno en el data de mi app.

Este es mi código html.

```
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="comment">Equipamiento:</label>
                <div class="input-group error-equipamiento">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i></span>
                        <select class="form-control Select2" v-model="C019CodigoMCRE">
                          <option value="" :selected="true">Seleccione Un Equimiento</option>
                          <option v-for="C019Equipamiento in C019Equipamientos" v-bind:value="C019Equipamiento.C019CodigoMCRE">{{ C019Equipamiento.C019NombreCRE }}</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

mi js

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
data: {
        C019Equipamientos:[],
        C019CodigoMCRE:''
    },
    methods: {
         C019Guardar:function(){

        console.log(this.C019CodigoMCRE)

       }
   }
})
```

Este es mi json para cargar el select (respuesta ajax)

```
{
   "Table":[
      {
         "C019CodigoMCRE":22,
         "C019NombreCRE":"22/Vidas Blue 2"
      },
      {
         "C019CodigoMCRE":24,
         "C019NombreCRE":"24/Gene Up"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar la funcion onchange

```
<select class="form-control Select2" v-model="C019CodigoMCRE" name="LeaveType" @change="onChange($event)">
                          <option value="" :selected="true">Seleccione Un Equimiento</option>
                          <option v-for="C019Equipamiento in C019Equipamientos" v-bind:value="C019Equipamiento.C019CodigoMCRE">{{ C019Equipamiento.C019NombreCRE }}</option>
                        </select>
```

ahora tu funcion onChange debe estar en la seccion methods, pruebalo:

```
<script>
var vm = new Vue({
    data: {
        key: ""
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(event) {
            console.log(event.target.value)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

puedes intentar

```
@change="(e)=>onChange(e)"
```

Comment: No me funciona tampoco @change="onChange($event)" aun teniendo el metodo en mis methods... no se que pasa, no hace nada.